# Selenium webdriver not working same in docker container

Tags: selenium-webdriver

after driver.get(url) statement , it is not able to fetch anything in docker container while in local it is working fine .

[Screenshot obtained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaNiX.png)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rw7D.png)

It's working well from local

[When ran from vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYD8s.png)

[Chrome options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVtKq.png)

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.